# How to convert these (hex) numbers to characters in Golang?

Tags: python, go, hex, decode

I receive some characters over a radio chip which I try to read out from a serial port. I can read it out fine in [this Python code](https://pastebin.com/wEm4EMnL), which gives me this:

```
received: counter: 2703
received: counter: 2704
received: counter: 2705
```

So using the [go-serial package](https://github.com/jacobsa/go-serial) I wrote some code to do the same in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "github.com/jacobsa/go-serial/serial"
import "io"
import "encoding/hex"


func main() {
        // Set up options.
        options := serial.OpenOptions{
                PortName: "/dev/ttyUSB0",
                BaudRate: 9600,
                DataBits: 7,
                StopBits: 2,
                MinimumReadSize: 4,
        }

        // Open the port.
        port, err := serial.Open(options)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("serial.Open: %v", err)
        }
        defer port.Close()

        for {
                buf := make([]byte, 32)
                n, err := port.Read(buf)
                if err != nil {
                        if err != io.EOF {
                                fmt.Println("Error reading from serial port: ", err)
                        }
                } else {
                        buf = buf[:n]
                        fmt.Println("received: ", buf)
                        fmt.Println("received: ", hex.EncodeToString(buf))
                }
        }
}
```

As you can see I print out the received buffer both raw AND converted from hex to string. The result is this:

```
received:  [99 111 117 110 116 101 114 58 32 51 48 50 52 10]
received:  636f756e7465723a20333032340a
received:  [99 111 117 110 116 101 114 58 32 51 48 50 53 10]
received:  636f756e7465723a20333032350a
received:  [99 111 117 110 116 101 114 58 32 51 48 50 54 10]
received:  636f756e7465723a20333032360a
```

I guess those numbers represent `counter: 2704`, but as you can see the conversion to string doesn't give me the result I expect.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I convert those numbers to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text that came in is already a valid string.  It's just that you have the bytes stored in `buf` which is `[]byte`.  To convert the existing `[]byte` to a value of type `string`:

```
asString := string(buf)
```

While `hex.EncodeToString` returns a string, it returns the hexadecimal representation of each byte.  For instance, the UTF-8 / ASCII for lowercase `c`, code 99 decimal, is `0x63`, so the first two characters of `hex.EncodeToString` are `6` and `3`.

(Meanwhile, you should figure out what to do with actual errors.  Your code currently ignores them, after announcing any that are not `io.EOF`.  If your device goes into an error state, you will loop over and over again getting the same error.)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the solution is very simple. Instead of either of these:

```
fmt.Println("received: ", buf)
fmt.Println("received: ", hex.EncodeToString(buf))
```

I simply had to do this:

```
fmt.Println("received: ", string(buf))
```